# How to terminate CXF webservice call within Callable upon Future cancellation

Tags: java, cxf, future, interrupt, callable

**Edit**

This question has gone through a few iterations by now, so feel free to look through the revisions to see some background information on the history and things tried.

---

I'm using a CompletionService together with an ExecutorService and a Callable, to concurrently call the a number of functions on a few different webservices through CXF generated code.. These services all contribute different information towards a single set of information I'm using for my project. The services however can fail to respond for a prolonged period of time without throwing an exception, prolonging the wait for the combined set of information.

To counter this I'm running all the service calls concurrently, and after a few minutes would like to terminate any of the calls that have not yet finished, and preferably log which ones weren't done yet either from within the callable or by throwing an detailed Exception.

Here's some highly simplified code to illustrate what I'm doing already:

```
private Callable<List<Feature>> getXXXFeatures(final WiwsPortType port, 
final String accessionCode) {
    return new Callable<List<Feature>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Feature> call() throws Exception {
            List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
            //getXXXFeatures are methods of the WS Proxy
            //that can take anywhere from second to never to return
            for (RawFeature raw : port.getXXXFeatures(accessionCode)) {
                Feature ft = convertFeature(raw);
                features.add(ft);
            }
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                log.error("XXX was interrupted");
            return features;
        }
    };
}
```

And the code that concurrently starts the WS calls:

```
WiwsPortType port = new Wiws().getWiws();
List<Future<List<Feature>>> ftList = new ArrayList<Future<List<Feature>>>();
//Counting wrapper around CompletionService, 
    //so I could implement ccs.hasRemaining()
CountingCompletionService<List<Feature>> ccs = 
        new CountingCompletionService<List<Feature>>(threadpool);
ftList.add(ccs.submit(getXXXFeatures(port, accessionCode)));
ftList.add(ccs.submit(getYYYFeatures(port accessionCode)));
ftList.add(ccs.submit(getZZZFeatures(port, accessionCode)));

List<Feature> allFeatures = new ArrayList<Feature>();
while (ccs.hasRemaining()) {
            //Low for testing, eventually a little more lenient
    Future<List<Feature>> polled = ccs.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (polled != null)
        allFeatures.addAll(polled.get());
    else {
        //Still jobs remaining, but unresponsive: Cancel them all
        int jobsCanceled = 0;
        for (Future<List<Feature>> job : ftList)
            if (job.cancel(true))
                jobsCanceled++;
        log.error("Canceled {} feature jobs because they took too long",
                        jobsCanceled);
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having with this code is that the Callables aren't actually canceled when waiting for port.getXXXFeatures(...) to return, but somehow keep running. As you can see from the `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) log.error("XXX was interrupted");` statements the interrupted flag *is* set after port.getFeatures returns, this is only available after the Webservice call completes normally, instead of it having been interrupted when I called Cancel.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can stop the running CXF Webservice call after a given time period, and register this information in my application?

Best regards, Tim

Comment: To trap the cancel inside, use the isCancelled() method. Your cancel call should cause InterruptedException inside too if you are blocked on a wait/IO.

Comment: isCancelled() is only available on the Future, whereas my code resides in the Callable, so that first line wont work.. As for the second line: I've tried (but as I said, poorly) to catch any kind of exception within the Callable, but was so far unable to do so.. Enclosing all the lines in call() within a try / catch block for InterruptedException fails because of an unreachable catch block exception because the Exception is never thrown from the try statement body. (Or so Eclipse says ;)) Is there any ugly old stuff from the feared Thread class that could help here?

Comment: It should be, as cancellation causes IntExc on *some* blocking operation. I had trouble with this assumption however: not every blocking is interruptible that way - I think synchronized() is such an example (used frequently in libs). One kill option would be to somehow gain access to the underlying IO operation and use an asynchronous close() on it. If you extend FutureTask, you gain both Callable and Future options, have you tried that?

Comment: Can you share us the details of the port.getFeatures() call. As it seems we are on our own, please clean up your answer and all the current code samples (perhaps move it to an external location and reference it).

Comment: Ok, it turns out my Callable is unaffected by the Future.cancel I'm calling: The Thread.interrupted flag is set, but the port.getFeatures call is not terminated (though I'd like it to be). This is weird stuff but there doesnt seem to be much of a way around it, is there?

Comment: The port.getFeatures code is an interface generated by Apache CXF, so port is a Proxy instance returned from javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(...) that supports the service endpoint interface..

Comment: Then I would look into the source of Apache CXF, isn't there some close() or cancel() method on that? WHat is your base endpoint interface you pass in to getPort()? I guess CXF has support for asynchronous calls as well so maybe there could be a feature there.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was just looking into that.. Not sure If I'll rephrase this question or close it and open a new one, but it turns out the CXF proxy is unaffected by the cancel / interrupt and continues running until completion.. After that `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` returns true, so for the moment I'm using that to log the failed call urls.. I'll have to look into if / why  the port just silently swallows the interrupt and continues running without a problem.. This is obviously the thing that should be killed of when calling cancel.

Comment: To close it you need voters for close - I can't do that with my rep. As I mentioned - we are practically alone, with very low view rate. Just change your question. Or if you think the CXF anomaly is a bug, then you could just post your answer about the findings and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 3** New answer.

I see these options:

- Post your problem on the Apache CXF as feature request
- Fix ACXF yourself and expose some features.
- Look for options for asynchronous WS call support within the Apache CXF
- Consider switching to a different WS provider (JAX-WS?)
- Do your WS call yourself using RESTful API if the service supports it (e.g. plain HTTP request with parameters)
- <strike>For über experts only: use true threads/thread group and kill the threads with unorthodox methods.</strike>

Comment: Sorry but how would this work? You can't simply 'cancel' the Callable.. You can only cancel the *Future* returned when you submit the Callable.. I can't see how I would be able to get the url from the Callable once it is lost after submitting it to the Executor..

Comment: Rephrased the question as the logging isn't the problem anymore: The problem is the webservice calls not being canceled in the first place! Thanks for the help so far, lets see what new answers this rephrasing brings..

Comment: I will adjust my answer too, so it doesn't attract downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The CXF docs have some instructions for setting the read timeout on the HTTPURLConnection:
http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

That would probably meet your needs.   If the server doesn't respond in time, an exception is raised and the callable would get the exception.  (except there is a bug where is MAY hang instead.  I cannot remember if that was fixed for 2.2.2 or if it's just in the SNAPSHOTS right now.)