# Is there a way to terminate CXF web service call?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am using CXF to call web service. It is used in a simple way like it is described in the documentation:

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();
Hello client = service.getHelloHttpPort();

String result = client.sayHi("Joe");
```

How can I terminate this service call when it takes time?

I found only one related question but this doesn't provide any solution.

[How to terminate CXF webservice call within Callable upon Future cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120783/how-to-terminate-cxf-webservice-call-within-callable-upon-future-cancellation)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a function of the web server. For example, if you use Jetty to serve your CXF content, then you can set the thread pool to something that'll watch your threads.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(...);
ExecutorService svc = new ControlledExecutorService(pool);
server.setThreadPool(new org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutorThreadPool(svc));
```

Then for the custom executor service (sorry, all code typed in the browser directly. I'm on an iPad with no Java. So you'll likely need to make slight adjustments, but the useful parts should be here):

```
public class ControlledExecutorService implements ExecutorService {
    private ExecutorService es;

    public ControlledExecutorService(ExecutorService wrapped) {
        es = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final Runnable command) {
        Future<Boolean> future = submit(new Callable< Boolean >() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                command.run();
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Do the proper monitoring of your Future and interrupt it
        // using Future.cancel(true) if you need to.
    }
}
```

Be sure to pass `true` to [cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) so that it sends the interrupt.

Also remember than just like with any thread, just because you send it an interrupt, it doesn't mean it'll comply. You have to do some work in your threads to make sure they're well behaved. Notably, periodically check `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and properly handling `InterruptedException` to pick it up and stop the task gracefully instead of just letting the exception blow everything up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately cancel(true) does not interrupt web service call. This is also discussed in the mentioned link. One possible solution could be using MTOM but in this case configuration on server side is required.